# White space in source tag of image causes incorrect URL in MVC 4 View

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this image tag in my MVC View:

```
$('.uploadedImage').prepend('<img height="50" width="50" src=/UploadedImages/' + data.result.name + '>');
```

The problem is when `data.result.name` (which is the file-name) contains `white-spaces`.

Eg: when the file name is something like this:

```
tempFile => <img src="/UploadedImages/tempFile" >
```

but if there is a white space then,

```
temp File => <img src="UploadedImages/temp" File" >
```

`data.result.name` is the file name returned as a parameter of a call back function (jquery) from my server.

how to correctly display the file name in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap image src in quotes

```
('.uploadedImage').prepend('<img height="50" width="50" src="/UploadedImages/' + data.result.name + '">');
```

Comment: Works great. This time, it correctly displays the white space. So, wrapping image src in quotes handles this white space by default ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., When you don't wrap attribute value with quotes, browser does it

Comment: So, thats why as soon as it sees an white-space it puts a double-quote but incorrectly. Thanks, I learnt a thing today.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. You should also HTML encode `data.result.name` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/413180 - Anentropic's answer. This can help secure your application against XSS.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: Thanks for that. Will go through.